# Problem adding 2 calculated fields in SSRS matrix report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've added 2 calculated fields to one of my datasets in my SSRS matrix report.  These 2 calculated fields below are trying to sum the values of a calculated column.

Here is a pic of the DESIGN tab in VS 2015:

[image]

Here are my attempts at creating the code for the 2 new calculated fields called PendingEffectiveness and ClosingRatio respectively:

```
=(IIF(Fields!FeatureType.Value = "BeginningPending", (Fields!FeatureCount.Value*100.0), 0) / IIF(Fields!FeatureType.Value = "FeaturesPending", (Fields!FeatureCount.Value),0))

=(IIF(Fields!FeatureType.Value = "ClosingFeatures", (Fields!FeatureCount.Value/100.0), 0) / IIF(Fields!FeatureType.Value = "NewFeatures", (Fields!FeatureCount.Value),0))
```

When I PREVIEW the report in VS 2015, the calculated columns that I added are NOT even showing up in the report.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the pic for the dataset1 properties:

[image]

I'm looking for results that look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. If I understand so far you have created two new calculated columns in Dataset1. Then you said the don't appear in the report, but I don't see them in the report design? There is also a potential divide by zero issue with the expression you have but one step at a time...

Comment: Alan, thanks for the reply.  The DataSet1 properties are above in the pic. Sorry I should have included that pic.  The column group contains that FeatureType in this matrix as shown above. I'm just now sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks

Comment: sorry, I'm still missing something... I thought you meant that PendingEffectiveness and ClosingRatio were not showing in the report. I don;t see then on the design anywhere though. Perhaps it would be useful to mock up the expected output in excel or something and post that as all the report loks like it will do at the moment is give you featurecount(s) by adjustername and featuretype. P.S. I'm in the UK so might not get back to you quickly

Comment: Sorry Alan.  I put a new pic up in the original message.  I think, if I'm not mistaken that I should be adding my new calculated columns to the COLUMN GROUP section of the matrix(?).  Can you confirm? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see from your update what you are trying to do. It won;t work the way you are approaching it. Your matrix column group is by featuretype so only values that appear in that column n the dataset will appear in the report. What you have done is basically add additional columns to the dataset but not use them. Calculated columns only act at the row level. Add a simple table (not matrix) to display your dataset and you'll see the output. What you actually want to add columns in the matrix and use expressions there to calculate your values. This is often not simple, but try and report back.

Comment: search SO for something like "ssrs difference between two columns in matrix" and you'll see similar questions. Personally I try to do as much as I can in the database. In this case (although not studied your requirements closely) I would calculate the results and then union them to the original data setting the 'FeatureType' ot the name of the calculation (e.g. ClosingRatio). This way your current simple matrix would work, no need for any additional expressions in the report.

Comment: I had actually done that using a pivot table in my SQL stored procedure where I had made those calculations and using only a table and NOT a matrix in SSRS I had run into the problem where SSRS would display the columns but NOT the data for some reason.